# switching between 99.xxx (webserver) and 192.xxx (TrueNAS) on a 10G mikrotik switch not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, webserver

Iperf3 from my webserver (99.xxx.9) to TrueNAS (192.168.1.80) is only 150Mb/s
but they are on the same 10G Mikrotik switch so I expect a few Gb/s.  I suspect my
routing config on my webserver is not correct but I could be wrong since if I
power off my Netgear GS106 there is no connectivity between my webserver and Truenas.

Iperf 192.xxx.80 to 192.xxx.90 is 3Gb/s as expected since old computers on 10G fiber.

Iperf 99.xxx.9 to 99.xxx.10 is 9.4Gb/s as expected since net computers on 10G fiber.

My network:

```
                          Microtik      NETGEAR        ATT PACE
                           CRS305       GS106          5268AC
Ubuntu 99.xxx.9 -----10G-----+
Ubuntu 99.xxx.10 ----10G-----+------1G----+------1G------+
Ubuntu 192.xxx.80 ---10G-----+            +              +
Ubuntu 192.xxx.90 ---10G-----+            +              +--- internet
                                          +              +
Windows 192.xxx.x -----------------1G-----+              +
                                                         +
Windows 192.xxx.x --------------------1G-----------------+
```

The AT&T Pace 5268AC does NAT for all the 192.xxx devices to the internet.

The AT&T Pace 5268AC has HTTP/HTTPS pinhole configured for the public IP address 99.xxx.9

The routing for 99.xxx.10 is

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         99.153.71.14    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0f0
99.153.71.8     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     100    0        0 enp2s0f0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 enp2s0f0
```

The Microtik is a switch, so should only use mac address.  It has factory default config.

Truenas is configured with static route in GUI
[image] but this appears to be not propaged to the "route" command.

```
root@truenas 192.168.1.80 [~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0f0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 kube-bridge
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0f0
```

I would appreciate help figuring out what I got wrong or diagnosing suggestions.

Comment: What's the routing table on the *other* device?

Comment: I updated the description to include truenas side. Something is wrong there.

Comment: thank you user1686.

Answer (score 0):

user1686 pointed me to the answer.

Truenas scale GUI for adding route did not propage the route to the kernel.
So entered the route via the command line

```
root@truenas[~]# ip route add 99.153.71.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev enp2s0f0
root@truenas[~]# route -e
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         homeportal      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp2s0f0
99.153.71.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0f0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 kube-bridge
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0f0
```

Now problem is gone